# TransferFunctionModel and BodePlot shows different result between Mathematica and MATLAB

Tags: plotting, matlab, control-systems

I was doing the `TransferFunctionModel` and `BodePlot`. But the result from Mathematica and MATLAB are different.

The function is as follows:

```
Bi = TransferFunctionModel[(1 + 3*I*ω)/(1 + 1.5*I*ω), ω];

BodePlot[Bi, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400, 
         FrameLabel -> {{{"Magnitude (db)", None}, {None, 
         "Frequency Transfer Function Inside"}}, {{"Phase(deg)", 
          None}, {"Frequency (rad/sec)", None}}}, 
         ScalingFunctions -> {{"Log10", "dB"}, {"Log10", "Degree"}}, 
         PlotRange -> {{{0, 100}, Automatic}, {{0, 100}, {0, 20}}}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
```

[image: Mathematica result]
[image: MATLAB result]

Comment: How is the phase treated in each case? Phase can be wrapped between 0 to 2Pi or unwrapped to go to infinity.

Comment: Actually in both cases I didn't specify the phase range. The phase range in MM has  negative part but in Matlab the phase is positive.

Comment: Without all the options in `BodePlot`,you'll get the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm getting a minimum phase of 0 in Mathematica as well.

```
Manipulate[tf = TransferFunctionModel[eq, s];

 BodePlot[tf, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500, 
  FrameLabel -> {{{"Magnitude (db)", None}, {None, 
      "Bode Plot"}}, {{"Phase(deg)", None}, {"Frequency (rad/sec)", 
      None}}}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {{"Log10", "dB"}, {"Log10", "Degree"}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{{0.1, 100}, Automatic}, {{0.1, 100}, 
     Automatic}}], {eq, (1 + 3 s)/(1 + 1.5` s)}]
```

[image]

Comment: But eq should be (1+3*i*s)/(1+1.5*i*s). Did you miss the "i"?

Comment: @yangyang Your use of "i" is non standard. Usually there are no imaginary units in the Laplace domain and you only get them when you replace s with i w. The Mathematica Bode plot does this for you. It assumes you are putting in an s-plane transfer function and want to plot it on the frequency axis. You need to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @yangyang As Hugh said, I substituted iw with s so that it would work with a document that I had written earlier that calculates from the Laplace space. As he also pointed out, your mistake was that TransferFunctionModel[] assumes Laplace domain and you didn't make the substitution of wi ->s. Now that I try it again using s*I, I'm getting the -300 you were mentioning earlier.

Comment: @BrianG I understand your point. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @BrianG I have another concern. The plot generated from Matlab is very sharp( the second pic looks like a Dirac function) while the one from MM has very wide peak. Is there any parameters I should use in MM?

Comment: @yangyang Make sure you have the same window and that it's logarithmic. Edit your original question and include your Matlab code. I'm not that good with Matlab, but someone else might be. The mathematica code should be right though, so it's likely an issue with your Matlab code.

Comment: @BrianG I added the code of Matlab and the results.

Comment: @BrianG I know what is the problem. If I use b=(1+3*s)/(1+1.5*s); then I got the same as MM. It seems the imaginary part "i" should not be there.